# Chrome url_handlers: allow opening of the original URL

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I'm using `url_handlers` in manifest.json to launch my chrome app when I visit example.com site. When I create new tab in chrome and write example.com in address line - the app starts, but the tab stays blank and doesn't load my page.

Is there a possibility or option to launch app with `url_hanlers` and still load my page?

Comment: Could you please share the callback handler code in your js?

Comment: You could be handling the url, but you'll still need to load the contents of the site into an open tab.

Answer (score 1):

There is no explicit support for such a thing in the `url_handlers` API per se. If you do insist on both loading your page and simultaneously launching your app, you could change the app to listen to a more specific URL than example.com (or a URL with a different origin altogether) and force that specific URL to load along with your page. This could be a dummy image, or an `<a>` tag that you'd click programmatically from a linked script, or perhaps even a `<link rel="import" href="...">` tag (I'd expect the latter to work, but it puts an additional restriction on the URL to be at the same origin as your main page -- otherwise you might have to deal with CORS prevention). So, one working example is:

- In your app's manifest:

`"url_handlers": {
   "launch-from-example-com": {
     "title": "...",
       "matches": [
         "http://example.com/app-starter"
       ]
    }
 }`

- In your page's HTML:

`<body>
    <a id="app-starter" href="http://example.com/app-starter"></a>
    ...
    <script>
      document.querySelector("#app-starter").click();
    </script>`

Is this what you need?